# Funny problem about stochastic integrals and Ito' s lemma

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider a probability filtred space  $ (\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal F_ t, \mathbb P)$ and a continuous $\mathcal F _t$-martingal starting from $0$, $ M = (M_t)_{t \geq 0}$, such that $\left \langle M \right \rangle_\infty \leq 1$ $\mathbb P$-ps.
Now, we define by recurence $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$  I^{(o)}_t \equiv  1, \ I^{(n+1)}_t = \int _0 ^t I^{(n)}_s d M_s \ , \ t \geq 0 $$

**The question:** How to show the following relation ?

$$ \forall n \geq 2 :  \ \ n I ^{(n)}_t = I ^{(n-1)}_t M_t - I ^{(n-2)}_t \left \langle M \right \rangle_t$$

**Elements of answer:**

Let's suppose by induction hypothesis that $(n -1) I ^{(n-1)}_t = I ^{(n-2)}_t M_t - I ^{(n-3)}_t \left \langle M \right \rangle_t$

By Ito's lemma, we have that

\begin{align} I ^{(n-1)}_t M_t &=  \int _0 ^t  I ^{(n-1)}_s dM_s+  \int _0 ^t   M_s \ d I ^{(n-1)}_s + \left \langle I ^{(n-1)},M \right \rangle_t 
\\& =I ^{(n)}_t +\int _0 ^t   M_s \ I ^{(n-2)}_s  d M_s+ \int _0 ^t    \ I ^{(n-2)}_s  \ I ^{(0)}_s d \left \langle M \right \rangle_s
\\&=  I ^{(n)}_t +\int _0 ^t  \left[ (n -1) I ^{(n-1)}_t+ I ^{(n-3)}_t \left \langle M \right \rangle_t\right]  d M_s+ \int _0 ^t    \ I ^{(n-2)}_s  \ I ^{(0)}_s d \left \langle M \right \rangle_s
\\& = nI ^{(n)}_t + \int _0 ^t   I ^{(n-3)}_t \left \langle M \right \rangle_t  d M_s+ \int _0 ^t    \ I ^{(n-2)}_s  \ I ^{(0)}_s d \left \langle M \right \rangle_s
\\ & \overset{\text{Ito's lemma}}{=} nI ^{(n)}_t +I ^{(n-2)}_t \left \langle M \right \rangle_t -\left \langle I ^{(n-2)},\left \langle  M \right \rangle\right\rangle_t\end{align}

which is almost the proof except the fact that I still don't know how to show that 
 $$\left \langle I ^{(n-2)},\left \langle  M \right \rangle\right\rangle_t=0$$

Someone can help me on it, please?

Comment: what makes it funny?!!

Comment: I don't know the definition of Ito's integral, but this feels like integration by parts to me.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, just keep in mind the chain rule in stochastic calculus is more involved, with a quadratic component.

Comment: It's probably a standard notation because no one here seems to ask, but what do the $\langle \rangle$ stand for here? I wish to understand what just happened. I know about stochastic processes and filtrations but I've never used Ito's integral.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thats the quadratic variation of the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes one line of argument to prove that :

$\left \langle I ^{(n-2)},\left \langle M \right \rangle\right\rangle_t=0$

You only need to observe that $< M >_t $ is a continuous finite variation process, so its quadratic covariation with any process is 0.

Best regards